# How to return id from insert into sqflite database in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, crud, sqflite

I have 2 databases. One for folders and one for notes.
The folder database contains a title and json String of a list of id's
The id's are supposed to represent the second database of notes. 
Basically folders needs to contain a list of notes and this is the best way I found so far. My problem is that when I create a new note and insert it into the database, I'm not sure how to get the id of the new note back.

If I set the id when I create the note then all notes will have the same id.
If I don't set the id then calling note.id returns null.
Based on my create function the Note's id should set itself (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)

My idea is that when creating the new Note I would somehow return the int id so that I could easily insert it into the folder. Here's what I have so far.

```
void addNewNote(Note note) async {
    var db_connection = await db;
    String query =
        'INSERT INTO Note(title, content, date_created, date_last_edited) VALUES(\'${note.title}\', \'${note.content}\', \'${note.date_created}\', \'${note.date_last_edited}\')';
    await db_connection.transaction((transaction) async {
      return await transaction.rawInsert(query);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inserted id is also returned from the `db.insert()` helper method, as the signature

```
Future<int> insert(String table, Map<String, dynamic> values, 
{String nullColumnHack, ConflictAlgorithm conflictAlgorithm})
```

describes. Example:

```
final db = await getDb();
final insertedId = await db.insert(
  todosTableName,
  todo.toMap(),
  conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
);
print('insertedId: $insertedId');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the id from the rawInsert like so:

```
final noteId = await transaction.rawInsert(query);
```

according to the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#raw-sql-queries

Instead of storing a string list of ids on the folders table you can also try store folder_id on the notes table as a foreign key:
https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html